# Java login screen using a textfile

Tags: java, text, file, authentication

I am creating a java application and I need to get the user PINs from the text file. I used the following code below, but is it not working properly. Could anyone please help me out soon.....

```
    String typedPIN="";   
    Menus obj1=new Menus();
    BufferedReader getIt=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userPIN="";
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("D:\\Studies\\BCAS\\HND\\Semester 1\\Programming Concepts\\Assignment\\AccountPIN.tab")));
        String strLine=null                    ;
        System.out.println("Enter PIN");
        userPIN=getIt.readLine();  
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {          
            if(userPIN.equals(strLine)){
                System.out.println("You have login!");
                obj1.MainMenu();
            }
        }    
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
 }
```

Comment: Define "not working properly". What exact behaviors are you seeing and how do these differ from what you would expect to see? What errors are you getting (if any)?

Comment: Could You attach the text in that file

Comment: PIN AccountNo Balance
1598 01-10-102203-0 95000
4895 01-10-102248-0 45000
9512 01-10-102215-0 125000
6125 01-10-102248 85000

Comment: I attached the text in the notepad file (above). I put each record in a new line and saved it. The problem with this code is that after I enter the PIN the program stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a login page in java console application using a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649207/creating-a-login-page-in-java-console-application-using-a-txt-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is your input data

```
PIN AccountNo Balance
1598 01-10-102203-0 95000
4895 01-10-102248-0 45000
9512 01-10-102215-0 125000
6125 01-10-102248 85000
```

You will need to split each line into its consituent parts, you could use the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class to do this, as it will let you extract the pin / account number as Strings and the balance as a Double/Integer.

At the moment you are comparing the user input against the whole line, so you would need to enter a pin `1598 01-10-102203-0 95000` rather than `1598` in order to login.

I suggest you split this into to two methods, one which when given a file returns a [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) of `Account` objects, and another which handles the login.

You could re-write your while loop to enable you to give a useful error message if you don't get a valid pin, e.g.

```
final File data = new File("D:\\Studies\\BCAS\\HND\\Semester 1\\Programming Concepts\\Assignment\\AccountPIN.tab");
Account userAcc = null;
for (Account acc : getAccounts(data)) {          
    if(userPIN.equals(acc.getPin())){
        userAcc = acc;
    }
}
if (userAcc == null) {
    obj1.MainMenu();
} else {
    // display error
}
```

Comment: i dont get how i should create an Account method (Account userAcc=null). Please help me I have tried this for days now with no result

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to implement `getAccounts`? or how to create an `Account` class?